# How to perform `git clean -fd` in SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit

How can I perform `git clean -fd` command using SmartGit? I searched in the menus but I didn't find anything suitable (except clean up in local menu, which I think it is not what I need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no pre-defined SmartGit command for this, but you may create an external **Tool** in the **Preferences** for this purpose.